# Typescript build error - what is wrong with this?

Tags: typescript

I have recently updated VS2017 and I am seeing a lot of typescript build errors.

The errors are all the same, and all relate to the validity of d.ts files.

Here is the some code in a d.ts file that is causing a typescript compilation error (TS2411):

```js
interface JQueryAjaxSettings {
}

interface DataSourceTransportCreate extends JQueryAjaxSettings {
    cache?: boolean;
    contentType?: string;
    data?: any;
    dataType?: string;
    type?: string;
    url?: any;
}

interface DataSourceTransport {
    create?: DataSourceTransportCreate;
    destroy?: DataSourceTransportDestroy;
    push?: Function;
    read?: DataSourceTransportRead;
    signalr?: DataSourceTransportSignalr;
    update?: DataSourceTransportUpdate;

    parameterMap?(data: DataSourceTransportParameterMapData, type: string): any;
}

interface DataSourceTransportOptions {
    success: (data?: any) => void;
    error: (error?: any) => void;
    data: any;
}

interface DataSourceTransportWithFunctionOperations extends DataSourceTransport {
    create?: (options: DataSourceTransportOptions) => void;
    destroy?: (options: DataSourceTransportOptions) => void;
    read?: (options: DataSourceTransportReadOptions) => void;
    update?: (options: DataSourceTransportOptions) => void;
}
```

The error is:

> TS2430    (TS) Interface 'DataSourceTransportWithFunctionOperations'
>   incorrectly extends interface 'DataSourceTransport'.   Types of
>   property 'create' are incompatible.
>       Type '(options: DataSourceTransportOptions) => void' has no properties in common with type 'DataSourceTransportCreate'.   Scripts
>   (tsconfig
>   project)  C:\Users****\typings\kendo\kendo.all.d.ts  1202    Active "

This error is repeated for a whole host of other properties.

My question is - is this definition valid? Has there been some change that would cause this to suddenly become invalid (i.e shown as a build error in VS)?

Comment: What is the type of DataSourceTransportCreate? Is it possible that you updated your typescript version and it broke some interfaces?

Comment: I have edited the answer to add the definiton for DataSourceTransportCreate.

Comment: AFAIK the typescript version is specified in my csproj file: <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.3</TypeScriptToolsVersion> and this hasn;t changed. Although my tsconfig file has this: "{
  "version": "1.8.0"," not sure if that is relevent to this issue.

Comment: Did it ever work? DataSourceTransportCreate does not match at all the type, your new type is a function

Comment: as @Axnyff remarked, in _interface DataSourceTransport_, _create?_ has type **DataSourceTransportCreate** and in _DataSourceTransportWithFunctionOperations_ has type **(options: DataSourceTransportOptions) => void**

Comment: @Axnyff - If you add an answer I will accept that!

Comment: I have been using this typings without noticing any errors until recently. It looks like the issue was raised here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/19081 - and there was always a compile error but I am now only seeing the issue due to recent tooling changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the definition is not valid. `DataSourceTransportWithFunctionOperations`'s override of `create(options: DataSourceTransportOptions): void` is not compatible with the base `create: DataSourceTransportCreate`, which isn't a function at all, but an options bag.

Typescript has only detected these errors with option bags since 2.4, and this particular one maybe only since 2.5, since it involves a method type. The change is probably that your latest VS update switched you from Typescript 2.3 or 2.4 or higher.

The underlying problem is that the kendo typings are out of date. As you found, the official typings got a fix in August. If you update your typings, most should be fixed to compile without errors on newer versions of Typescript.

Comment: Thanks. Latest update of VS2017 now seems to put TSC version `2.5.3` on it's PATH hence this issue. I was able to update the kendo typings but then had problems with knockout typings and other typings which I don't have time to fix. I found one other useful option in tsconfig file, under compiler options you can add: `"skipLibCheck": true`. This doesn't fix the issues, just leaves them hidden as before - so use with caution.